# Add a minimum and maximum to wtforms.widgets html5 NumberInput

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I would like to know how can I put a minimum and maximum to the forms in WTForms using the html5 widget.
I have tried min = 0, max = 100 / min = "0", max = "100" / min = 0(), max = 100(). But I get internal server errors

```
from wtforms import Form, StringField, RadioField, SelectField, TextAreaField, validators, IntegerField
from wtforms.widgets import html5
class CreateUserForm(Form):
TotalOrder = IntegerField('Total Order Amount', widget=html5.NumberInput())
```

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve it, apparantly I was supposed to put the min and max values inside the NumberInput()
So,

```
TotalOrder = TotalOrder = IntegerField('Total Order Amount', widget=html5.NumberInput(min = 0, max = 100))
```